# Payment method codes

Tags: payment-methods

I need the list of payment method codes.

My code

```
<?php 
require_once("../app/Mage.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::init();
echo "start<br>"; 

$allPaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();

foreach($allPaymentMethods as $pippo) {
    echo $pippo;
}

echo count($allPaymentMethods); 
echo "<br>";
$activePaymentMethods =Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

foreach($activePaymentMethods as $menelao) {
    echo $menelao;
}
echo count($activePaymentMethods);  
echo "<br>";

echo "end";
?>
```

It does not work. The array count works but `echo $pippo` and `$menelao` is blank.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Try to do this:

```
$allPaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();

foreach($allPaymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
    echo $paymentMethod->getCode();
}
```

The method getAllMethods() returns an array of payment method objects

```
/**
 * Retrieve all system payments
 *
 * @param mixed $store
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllMethods($store=null)
{
    $methods = array();
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment', $store);
    foreach ($config as $code => $methodConfig) {
        $data = $this->_getMethod($code, $methodConfig);
        if (false !== $data) {
            $methods[$code] = $data;
        }
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

That is why if you want to get the payment method code you need to call the method **getCode()** on the **$paymentMethod object**

Comment: Great, I updated my answer to add more details if you are interested. The other method you are calling "getActiveMethods" is also returning an array of payment method objects. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if this helped you.